# How do I graphically "pop" keystrokes and mouse clicks so they are useful in playback videos?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

GoTo Webinar does not support recording on the Mac, so I am going to be using iShowU HD Pro to record webinars.

A nice feature is that it shows keystrokes and mouse clicks and sounds on the recording, but it does not show on my screen as I'm interacting.

I'd like to disable the webinar's feature and have the graphical notifications occur on the real screen as I'm doing them.  In this way they will be presented to the webinar viewers, on the recording, and be visible to me as they occur.

How do I get these graphical pops to occur?

Answer (score 8):

[Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/) (as mentioned in the comment by Elijah).

> Mouseposé 3 is an essential tool for everyone doing presentations or demos. If turned on, it dims the screen and puts a spotlight on the area around the mouse pointer, easily guiding the audience‘s attention to an area of interest.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is an open source project on Github called [keycastr](https://github.com/sdeken/keycastr) works fine on Mac OSX 10.8, I have built it from source code.

After I upgrade my system to 10.9, it doesn't work by default. I have to add it here:

```
System Perferences -> Security & Privacy #Privacy
```

There is still another problem: I can't build it again under Xcode 5.

The version is 0.8.0. Seems that this project was deprecated by author. Any one want to fork this project and fix it?

Comment: Tested today and [keycastr](https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr) works well (on macOS 10.12) if installing the more recently updated "canonical" version (https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr) using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh): `brew cask install keycastr`

Comment: For those who are having trouble installing keycastr via Homebrew, the command to install the cask is now `brew install --cask keycastr`.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Keycodes.app](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) to display keystrokes. Bonus: it can show both make and break.

[image]

Comment: I also found Mousepose which works nicely with showuhd and gotomeeting webinar. It isn't opensource nor free but worked nicely. It does Keyboard strokes but cannot keep entire strings of text up for a specified text. Fr instance, if I enter a username into a text field it shows each charcter on the screen one right after the other but not at the same time. The mouse feature worked great though and even dims the entire screen except for the active user definable radius around the mouse.

http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/

Answer (score 1):

[PinPoint from Lagente](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinpoint/id408265505?mt=12) also does this. Less expensive too (5$ or so).

> PinPoint is a menubar item which displays an animated graphic around your pointer. It can help locate the pointer on your screen or multiple screens. It is also a great way to enhance your pointer with fun animated graphics!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution for how to make mouse clicks would be to use [Did I Click](http://geni.us/2KFS).  It only makes mouse clicks more visible, but it is cheaper than both PinPoint and Mouseposé.

Here's a screenshot with the options [image]